# Javascript & Webpack: Error: Unknown option '--watch-content-base'

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack-5, webpack-cli

I am trying to integrate WebPack into the scripts my package.json file. I was following a video to try and do it and it works fine up until I enter 'npm start'.

I get an error message in the terminal reading:

```
[webpack-cli] Error: Unknown option '--watch-content-base'
[webpack-cli] Run 'webpack --help' to see available commands and options
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! frontend@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --watch-content-base --open`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

And I cannot understand why I'm getting this error considering in the video I was following it works just fine. If I remove ' --watch-content-base' it works but I'm trying to make sure any code changes are automatically updated on the server.

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --watch-content-base --open",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.51.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web pack 5 doesn't have `contentBase` anymore but `static` instead for content in the dev server. You should delete the previous main.js inside your dist folder and paste this chunk of code in webpack.config.js then run `npx webpack-dev-server` in the terminal.
Remember to put all your HTML code, CSS code and images inside one directory and open `localhost:8080` in a browser.

```js
const path = require('path');
    
module.exports = {
    entry: ' path of index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    devServer: {
        static: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        compress: true,
        port: 8080,
    },
    mode: 'development'
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could run the versions that are being used in the video.
Have a look at the `package.json` file to see which versions you are currently using.

Installation of a specific version:

```
$ npm i webpack@4.43.0 webpack-cli@3.3.12 webpack-dev-server@3.11.0
```